# how to use multiple frames in a canvas with scrollbar in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am building a GUI app for showing some data results.I want to show name and some details in a frame for each result I have.So I created a frame and a canvas inside of it.Now I want to place multiple frames in canvas with scrollbars but it didn't seems to work .So I tried to place results in multiple canvas but its is also not working with scrollbar.Here is a snipet of it.

```
from tkinter import *

class Results:
    def __init__(self,master,topic = None):
        self.result_frame = Frame(master, bg = '#ffffff', bd =5)
        self.result_frame.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.25, relwidth = 1,relheight = 
        0.75, anchor ='n')

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.result_frame,bg = 
        '#ffffff',bd=0,width=500,height=500)
        self.canvas.place(relx = 0.0, rely = 0.0 )

        self.sbar = Scrollbar(self.result_frame, orient = 'vertical')
        self.sbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.sbar.place(relx = 0.98,width = 14 ,relheight = 0.5 )

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.sbar.set)

        self.rframe = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.rframe.pack()

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.rframe, anchor="nw")
        self.show_results()

    def create_rcanvas(self,name,y) :
        name = Canvas(self.rframe, bg = '#4da6ff')
        name.place(relx=0.25,rely = y, relwidth = 0.55,height = 100)


    def show_results(self):
        y = 0.1
        for i in range(0,10):
            name = 'can'+str(i)
            name = Canvas(self.canvas, bg = '#4da6ff')
            name.place(relx=0.25,rely = y, relwidth = 0.55,height = 100)
            y = y + 0.2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('600x600')
    Results(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Kindly provide me solution and please try to run and check it first.

Comment: when you say _"multiple frames in canvas with scrollbars"_, does that mean N frames and N scrollbars, or a single scrollbar that controls N frames?

Comment: Here check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter

Comment: one scollbar with multiple frames